# Why is the dict.keys not iterable?

Tags: python

`node_name` is a string. Shouldn't this return a list of keys in the node_list dictionary, which can be iterated over? Why does the error say it is not iterable?

```
class Graph:

def __init__(self):
    self.node_list = {}
    self.number = 0

def node(self, node_name):
    if node_name in self.node_list.keys: 
    ...

File "PythonProject2.3.py", line 10, in node
    if node_name in self.node_list.keys: #returns list of keys
TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable
```

Comment: I'm no expert, but it looks like `keys` is a function that you need to call: `if node_name in self.node_list.keys()`

Answer (score 12):

`.keys` is a function, not a property. Try this instead:

```
if node_name in self.node_list.keys():
```

A dictionary iterates over its keys by default, though, so this will work, too:

```
if node_name in self.node_list:
```

Comment: In fact iteration is a bit of a red herring here. Both the dictionary object and the thing returned by `keys()` in Python 3 support a containment test directly, no need to iterate, although as it happens they do also support iteration. The error about the function object `keys` not being iterable is because iteration is the last thing that Python tries before giving up on performing `in`

Comment: @SteveJessop - I very much like your explanation. IMHO it better answers the question. Should be an  answer so that people can upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
if node_name in self.node_list.keys():
```

to

```
if self.node_list.has_key(node_name):
```

Answer (score 0):

Python sees `node_name in self.node_list.keys`, so it evaluates `self.node_list.keys` and then tries to work out whether or not `node_name` is in the result of that.

`self.node_list.keys` is a function (you should have written `keys()`), but all that's really relevant here is that it doesn't support the Python `in` operator. That is to say, you can't test whether or not something is in `self.node_list.keys`.

The reason you specifically get an error about iteration, is that Python first checks for the `__contains__` function and, if not present, tries to iterate over the right-hand operand of `in` comparing each value against the left-operand using `==`. This fails, hence the exception you saw. The reason Python does that is just so that anything which supports iteration also supports `in` automatically. Albeit perhaps not very efficiently.